# Can i run php unit tests using Laravel Policy in route middleware?

Tags: laravel, unit-testing

I am using Laravel policies to control authorisation on my api routes. I want to only allow the current user to update their own post. This works fine when i manually run it through the application, but the unit tests fail. The unit tests, redirect to the login screen.

route:

```
Route::post('/posts/{post:reference}/editDetails', [PostDetailsApiController::class, 'update'])
   ->middleware('can:update,post');
```

policy:

```
public function update(User $user, Post $post)
{
   return $post->user_id === $user->id;
}
```

unit test:

```
$this->user = User::factory()->create();
$post = Post::factory()->create(['user_id' => $this->user->id]);
Passport::actingAs($this->user);
$response = $this->call('POST', 'http://test/api/posts/' . $post->reference . '/editDetails');
$response->assertStatus(200);
```

but this test fails saying 'Failed asserting that 200 is identical to 302'. If i add followingRedirects() and actingAsClient then it passes. If i dd in the controller, it doesnt get fired, so i'm pretty sure the controller isnt getting hit? if i remove the middleware, it runs fine. any advice welcomed. thanks

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with the policy as the status code 302 is a redirect. The problem lies within this snippet.

```
$this->call('POST', 'http://test/api/posts/' . $post->reference . '/editDetails');
```

Normally you would call it with a relative `URL`.

```
$this->call('POST', 'api/posts/' . $post->reference . '/editDetails');
```

A better approach is to use the route helper for named routes. I have a example [project](https://github.com/mrhn/Centerplan/blob/master/tests/Feature/Account/AccountDeleteTest.php), where i used this approach.

```
$this->call('POST', route('posts.edit-details', ['reference' => $post->reference]));
```

Remember to add a name to your route.

```
Route::post('/posts/{post:reference}/editDetails', [PostDetailsApiController::class, 'update'])
    ->middleware('can:update,post')
    ->name('posts.edit-details');
```

Comment: as mentioned above, the tests do work if i remove the middleware. thanks for you example project anyway.

Comment: but there is nothing in that policy that returns a redirect, then you need to include more code or figure what is causing that redirect. If i remember correctly, if login is setup incorectly it can redirect to the login page, maybe try to get the header data from the redirect and see where it redirects too?